# What is the keyevent code for the overview key?

Tags: android, adb

What event code needs to be sent for the overview key with `adb shell input keyevent <code>`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean the button that shows the list of opened apps, it's [KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH):

> KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
>
> Added in API level 11 int KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH Key code constant: App
>   switch key. Should bring up the application switcher dialog.
>
> Constant Value: 187 (0x000000bb)

For using it with adb shell input, you can simply use the name:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH
```